# Creating a new object in a view which passes IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a bit of pain trying to solve how can I create a new object when I'm passing to my view a IEnumerable.I'm having the creation of the new item in a modal jquery-ui window on the same page.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor( model =>model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "Please choose a title that is not empty or less than 3 symbols")
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is the code snippet that I'm trying to implement in the main view from where my js gets the information,but since my model is a collection I cannot access the editor options in my razor view.

This is a part of my js file where I get the values of the items inside the input boxes listed above which do NOT work becase I'm operating on a collection.I cannot change the model so I need a shortcut through it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Course/Create/",
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        Title: $("#itemTitle").val(),
        CourseDescription: $("#itemDescription").val(),
        CourseCategory: $("#itemCategory").val()
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a View Model that will contain both the IEnumerable collection + an object that you would like to submit (with Title, Description and Category properties).

In case you cannot change the model that you are passing to the view you should not use Html.EditorFor but simply Html.Editor (the same applies to Html.LabelFor and other Html extensions that you use there).
Of course you then need to pass appropriate name parameter ( e.g. "itemTitle") to these extensions that will comply with the ones used in the JS code.